# Decomposition of a Toeplitz matrix into sum of two circulant matrices (matlab/octave)

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have to solve a linear system `Tx=b` where T is a `n x n` symmetric toeplitz matrix. Any toeplitz matrix can be decomposed into a sum of a circulant matrix U and a skew-cirulant matrix V, i.e. `T=U+V`.

This is useful because every `n x n` real valued circulant matrix C has the decomposition `C=F*ΛF`, where F is the `n x n` Fourier matrix, F* is its conjugate transpose and `Λ=diag(λ0,λ1,...,λn-1)` is the diagonal matrix of the eigenvalues of C. The eigenvalues can be computed as `λj=sum{from k=0 to n-1} c_k*exp(-2*pi*i*j*k/n) (j=0,...,n-1 and i is the imaginary unit)`, where c_k is the kth element of the first line of C, i.e. `c=[c0,c1,...,cn-1]`.

Moreover a `n x n` matrix W is said to be a {ω}-circulant matrix if it has the decomposition `W=Ω*F*ΛFΩ`, where * is the conjugate transpose symbol, F is the Fourier Matrix, Λ is a diagonal matrix containing the eigenvalues of W, and `Ω=diag{1,ω^(-1/n),ω^(-2/n),...,ω^(-(n-1)/n)}`, where `ω=exp(i*θ)` with `θ∈[-pi,pi]`. In our case ω=1 for U (circulant) and ω=-1 for V (skew-cirulant).

Since, in my case, T is symmetric, it is easy to compute U and V. Let `t=(t0,t1,...,tn-1)` be the vector that generate T, i.e. `T=toeplitz(t)`, so `U=toeplitz([t0,t1+tn-1,t2+tn-2,...,tn-1+t1])` and `V=toeplitz([t0,t1-tn-1,t2-tn-2,...,tn-1-t1])`.

I tried to decompose in this way a random symmetric toeplitz on matlab: I successfully created U and V, verifying that U+V==T; then I computed the eigenvalues of U (using the formula above) and the decomposition of U, verifying that U is equal to its decomposition. But in the case of V the decomposition I computed is not the same to V, also the eigenvalues I computed are not equal to the ones computed using the default command eig(V); lastly even by using the eigenvalues computed with the default command, the decomposition is not equal to V, so I made a mistake somewhere but I cannot understand where.

Here is the code I used in the test.

```
A = magic(3);
t = A(1,:);
n = length(t);
T = toeplitz(t);

% creating the Fourier matrix ------------
F = ones(n);
f = zeros(n-1);
w = exp(-2*pi*1i/n);
for i = 1:n-1
    for j = i:n-1
        f(i,j) = w^(i*j);
    end
end
F(2:end,2:end) = f - diag(diag(f)) + f.';
F = 1/sqrt(n)*F;

% creating U and V ------------
u = zeros(1,n);
u(1) = 1/2*t(1);
v = zeros(1,n);
v(1) = 1/2*t(1);
for i = 2:n
    u(i) = 1/2*(t(i) + t(n-(i-2)));
    v(i) = 1/2*(t(i) - t(n-(i-2)));
end
U = toeplitz(u);
V = toeplitz(v);
% U+V==T

% eigenvalues of U ------------
eigU = zeros(1,n);
for j = 1:n
    for k = 0:n-1
        eigU(j) = eigU(j) + u(k+1)*exp(-2*pi*1i*(j-1)*k/n);
    end
end
% F'*diag(eigU)*F
% U

% eigenvalues of V ------------
eigV = zeros(1,n);
omega = zeros(1,n);
w = -1;
for j = 1:n
    for k = 0:n-1
        eigV(j) = eigV(j) + v(k+1)*exp(-2*pi*1i*(j-1)*k/n);
    end
    omega(j) = w^(-(j-1)/n);
end
diag(omega)'*F'*diag(eigV)*F*diag(omega)
F'*diag(eigV)*F
V
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot here that you could do more efficiently (i.e., most of this can be replaced by using the FFT and matrix multiplies instead of loops), but the specific problem you're running into here is that you're not using the roots of -1 in the calculation of the eigenvalues of V, you're using the roots of unity.

What you want is

```
 eigV(j) = eigV(j) + v(k+1)*exp(-2*pi*1i*(2*j-1)*k/(2*n));
```

Comment: thank you for the reply, it works! Is it possible for you to explain me more about the roots of -1 and of 1 ? I was using the eigenvalues formula above without knowing well its actual meaning. Thanks again

Comment: It's unclear to me how the decomposition is ultimately going to help you solve a linear system, as the eigenvalues of those two component matrices aren't going to directly give you the eigenvalues of the original matrix. But, the short answer is that circulant matrices are diagonalized by the DFT matrix, which is a Vandermonde matrix of the roots of unity (1), while skew-circulant matrices are diagonalized by a "shifted" DFT matrix, which is a Vandermonde matrix of the roots of -1. A good resource is Pan's "Structured Matrices and Polynomials: Unified Superfast Algorithms".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation about the roots of unity. In the paper I am reading they say that the decomposition allows to reduce the number of FFT's needed in the computation of the matrix-vector product. You can read all the info [here](https://i.imgur.com/jSvptWN.png)

Comment: I see, so it's for a preconditioned iterative solver.  If you know the system is nonsingular (and not too poorly conditioned), you might instead consider a direct solver.  There are both O(N^2) and O(N log^p N) Toeplitz solvers that exist.

Comment: I forgot to ask 2 things, has the "shifted" DFT matrix an official name? And, how to compute the eigenvalues of V by means of FFT? Because for example, I can compute eigenvalues of U using the command `fft(u)` where u is the first line of U, but with V fft(v) or ifft(v) does not work.

Comment: I don't know of any particular name for that matrix, though it wouldn't surprise me if it existed in literature somewhere.  More generally it's a (unitary) Vandermonde matrix.  To get eigenvalues with the FFT you can just do `fft(omega(:) .* V(:,1))`.  The "omega" vector performs a modulation that corresponds to a shift in the frequency domain.

Comment: Oh, it would never came to my mind to use that command to compute eigenvalues of V. Thanks for all sir.

I tried with a system matrix of size 500 and computed its determinant and condition number, it says `Det(T)=Inf` and `cond(T)=6.45`. So the matrix is nonsingular and well conditioned?

Comment: Also, what does the sentence "The omega vector performs a modulation that corresponds to a shift in the frequency domain" actually mean? Is omega a sort of permutation matrix?

Comment: I'm referring to a generalization of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Shift_theorem .  Modulating the input data by a complex exponential of a fixed frequency (which is what `omega` is) amounts to a shift in the Fourier domain.  In this case, `omega` is shfiting by a "half index", and so the spectrum of the signal is interpolated on the complex unit circle at the roots of -1 rather than the roots of 1.

Comment: Mm this is too difficult for me, I'm new to this topic. I tried to understand and read about the [shifted DFT](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/dba5cd1b469b2cbc925c4abd9ea32c62ba41f89c), I suppose we used `a=0` and `b=1/2` in our case to compute the eigenvalues of V, right?